# JavaScript toISOString() doesn't work in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I am writing a date validation function by using JavaScript.

```
function dateCheck(dateString) {
   try {
      return null != new Date(dateString).toISOString();
   }
   catch (error) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

This function works fine in Chrome, however, in IE and Firefox, I input an invalid date like "11/32/2015", it will regard it as "12/2/2015". I put an invalid date like "23/1/2015", it will regard it as "11/1/2016". I thought toISOString() function can return null if the input date is invalid, but it seems it doesn't.

Comment: Wouldn't the blame lie on the Date constructor instead of `toISOString()` itself? You're not passing valid date formats to that constructor, by the way.

Comment: What makes you think `toISOString` behaves like this? The `Date` constructor will attempt to parse the date. If it produces a valid date (even if the string was invalid), `toISOString` will stringify it. Otherwise, it will throw an error. Never `null`.